# Bayes classifier program to predict the class of give information in java?

Tags: java, naivebayes

My code:

```
package try2;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class bayes  
{
    JFrame frame;
    JTable table;
    JPanel panel;
    JScrollPane tableContainer;

    int i,j;
    int countC=0,countR=0,countS=0;
    int count=0;
    int[] CAge=new int[3];


    public bayes()
    {
          frame = new JFrame("JTable Test Display");

          panel = new JPanel();
          panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         String row[][]={{"consultancy","30","phd","9"},  
               {"service","21","mtech","1"}              ,
            {"research","26","mtech","2"},{"service","28","btech","10"},
            {"consultancy","40","mtech","14"},{"research","35","phd","10"},
            {"research","27","btech","6"},{"service","32","mtech","9"},
            {"consultancy","45","btech","17"},{"research","36","phd","7"}};

    String column[]={"job","age","qualification","experience"};
    table=new JTable(row,column);

     tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);

    panel.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);



    //work type count
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(table.getValueAt(i,0)=="consultancy")
        {
            countC++;
        }
        if(table.getValueAt(i,0)=="research")
        {
            countR++;
        }
        if(table.getValueAt(i,0)=="service")
        {
            countS++;
        }
    }


    //consultancy age count
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(((table.getValueAt(i, 0))=="consultancy") && ((Integer.parseInt((String)table.getValueAt(i, 1))>=20) && (Integer.parseInt((String)table.getValueAt(i, 1))<=30)) )
        {
          count++;  
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: illegal starting of expression error and  ; expected error occur at line marked as @@

Comment: What is the question?